# Is there a website that shows population sizes?

Tags: ecology, population-biology

I'm looking for a website that shows the population sizes of a species (doesn't matter which) as a function of time at a geographic coordinate. Is there a government website or other free database with such information?

Comment: Will humans do? You can probably get this from the OECD site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the Imperial College global population dynamics database.  They will have time series data at specific locations.  http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/cpb/databases/gpdd
There is a sister database as well that might be useful. http://lits.bio.ic.ac.uk:8080/litsproject/

These contain several hundred time series, and you can see a paper that used them here:  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2011.01702.x/abstract

Comment: My first idea as well, and definitely the best source around.

Comment: Would you happen to know one with more recent data (e.g. 2005 and above)? Thanks.